# Выполнение запроса в MySQL обновляет только первую строку в таблице tb_zgrading_21, как исправить?

Tags: mysql, sql

Выполнение запроса в `MySQL` обновляет только первую строку в таблице `tb_zgrading_21`, как исправить?

```
UPDATE tb_zgrading_21 SET tb_zgrading_21.`Баллы` =
(((SELECT `Вес квалификационного требования в %` FROM `tb_weightqualreq_21` WHERE tb_weightqualreq_21.`ID` = 1) * (SELECT `Баллы` FROM `tb_1gknowledgelevel` WHERE tb_1gknowledgelevel.`ID` = tb_zgrading_21.`Уровень знаний`))/100)+
(((SELECT `Вес квалификационного требования в %` FROM `tb_weightqualreq_21` WHERE tb_weightqualreq_21.`ID` = 2) * (SELECT `Баллы` FROM `tb_1gexperience` WHERE tb_1gexperience.`ID` = tb_zgrading_21.`Опыт`))/100)+
(((SELECT `Вес квалификационного требования в %` FROM `tb_weightqualreq_21` WHERE tb_weightqualreq_21.`ID` = 3) * (SELECT `Баллы` FROM `tb_1gcontentwork` WHERE tb_1gcontentwork.`ID` = tb_zgrading_21.`Содержание работы`))/100)+
(((SELECT `Вес квалификационного требования в %` FROM `tb_weightqualreq_21` WHERE tb_weightqualreq_21.`ID` = 4) * (SELECT `Баллы` FROM `tb_1gresponsibility` WHERE tb_1gresponsibility.`ID` = tb_zgrading_21.`Материальная ответственность`))/100)+
(((SELECT `Вес квалификационного требования в %` FROM `tb_weightqualreq_21` WHERE tb_weightqualreq_21.`ID` = 5) * (SELECT `Баллы` FROM `tb_1gresponsibility2` WHERE tb_1gresponsibility2.`ID` = tb_zgrading_21.`Ответственность за условия труда`))/100)+
(((SELECT `Вес квалификационного требования в %` FROM `tb_weightqualreq_21` WHERE tb_weightqualreq_21.`ID` = 6) * (SELECT `Баллы` FROM `tb_1ginteraction` WHERE tb_1ginteraction.`ID` = tb_zgrading_21.`Взаимодействие`))/100)+
(((SELECT `Вес квалификационного требования в %` FROM `tb_weightqualreq_21` WHERE tb_weightqualreq_21.`ID` = 7) * (SELECT `Баллы` FROM `tb_1gleadership` WHERE tb_1gleadership.`ID` = tb_zgrading_21.`Лидерство`))/100);
```

Вот ссылка на `SQL` код:

https://pastebin.com/y9K5TP9B

Comment: Я так думаю - добавить условие `where` в конце скрипта. Вы обновляете строку на какую-то сумму данных, а вот где обновить - не прописано. И получаете только одну сумму..она должна быть во всех ячейках столбца `Баллы`?

Comment: Да. Но where это наоборот уточняющая конструкция.

Comment: Смысл в том что конструкция должна подсчитать сумму для всех строк и указанных столбцов. Но делает это только для 1-ой строки. Ничего понять не могу.

Comment: Тогда согласен с вопросом..по идее должно обновляться все

Comment: Это очень странно, если он обновляет только одну строку. По тому что тут написано он должен обновить все

Comment: Я вижу так, что считается какая-то одна сумма и присваивается всем значениям в столбце. Как-то не очень логично. Потому и стоит добавить, что-то типа `where tb_zgrading_21.id = tb_weightqualreq_21.id`. Мне кажется такая логика у Вас заложена должна быть. Попробуйте для начала упростить и посмотреть, что получится из `UPDATE tb_zgrading_21 SET tb_zgrading_21.`Баллы` = 777`.

Comment: Причем если добавить даже в конце WHERE ID = 2; то MySQL пишет "запрос выполнен обновлено 0 строк". Что происходит вообще не пойму...

Comment: А сколько строк у Вас в таблице на данный момент? Что выводит комманда `SELECT count(*) FROM tb_zgrading_21`?

Comment: Простой запрос работает. Обновил 7 строк, как положено.

Comment: Осталось одно, из того, что я могу предложить - получить результат вот етой выборки...`SELECT `Вес квалификационного ....` отдельно. Может там какой-то баг с получением суммв? Сложно читается..

Comment: Если выполнить только 1 конструкцию до операции "+", то она тоже выполняется для всех 7 строк tb_zgrading_21

Comment: Ну вот..ищите ошибку в конкатенации выборки